# When I add a feature to a vector layer, all the features of the layer disappear Openlayers

Tags: openlayers, features

I'm working in a Geocoder tool that can put new features in a vector layer directly just pressing a button. When press the button all the features of
the layer **disappear** in the map. The features still exists because I can get 
the length increased by one using after that:

```
 alert(vector.getSource().getFeatures().length)
```

I did the following function as button click handler

```
function addPoint(lng,lat)
{
  var pp = new ol.geom.Point( [
    ol.proj.transform([lng,lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
]);
var featurething = new ol.Feature({
   geometry: pp
});
vector.getSource().addFeature(featurething); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ol.proj.transform returns Array. so it means,

```
var pp = new ol.geom.Point([[lng,lat]]);
```

there's useless square brackets. remove them, then it works.

```
var pp = new ol.geom.Point(
    ol.proj.transform([lng,lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
);
```